# How can I reduce the noise of prediction graph?

Tags: neural-networks, prediction, error, lstm, noise

I am trying to use LSTM to predict a time series data as you can see in the following image, the predicted graphs is very noisy:

[image]

The original data is looking like this:
[image]

That I normalized it like this and fed it to the LSTM network:

[image]

Is there a way to get better result with less noise?

EDIT: I use `keras` implementation of LSTM and `sklearn.preprocessing.normalize` library for normalization.

Comment: I don't think we can answer this as it stands now. What are these plots you are showing us? What are the values? Is this time series data? What software, functions are you using?

Comment: @user2974951: I edited my question. Yes the data is a time series that you can see in the second pic. And I used `sklearn.preprocessing.normalize` for normalization that you can see it's result in the last pic. I also use `kears` implementation of LSTM.

Comment: Then this has to do with model building. We would need to see your code, what you've done with some explanations.

Comment: @user2974951 In these situations, we've created canonical threads to serve as duplicate targets. See meta discussion here: https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5273/whats-the-best-way-to-answer-my-neural-network-doesnt-work-please-fix-quest